# invalid_request response when curl to google

Tags: php, curl

I am writing following code to get authorization token.

assigning authorization to code variable

```
$code =  $this->request->query['code'];
```

i have deleted my client secret to post question.

```
$clientSecret = "";
```

initializing curl

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        $header[]         = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,        true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode("code=".$code."&
                client_id=289710071999.apps.googleusercontent.com&
                client_secret=".$clientSecret."&
                redirect_uri=http://budzzflorist.localhost.com/users/google&
                grant_type=authorization_code"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $request_result = curl_exec($ch);
        print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
        echo "\n\ncURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch); // print error info
        echo "\n\ncURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
        var_dump( json_decode($request_result,true));
```

Comment: It looks like you're using CakePHP. You should have a look at the [`HttpSocket`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/http-socket) class.

Comment: i have that option but i want to do it with curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Google wants the form to be `application/x-www-urlencoded`.

Try this:

```
$ch           = curl_init();
$code         = '123';
$clientSecret = '45686';

$postFields = array('code'          => $code,
                    'client_id'     => '289710071999.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                    'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
                    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://budzzflorist.localhost.com/users/google',
                    'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,        true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postFields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$request_result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump( json_decode($request_result,true));
```

Result: `invalid_client` because my tokens are incorrect, but not `invalid_request`.

If you pass an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, cURL will force the content type to be `multipart/form-data` which is what causes invalid request.  Instead use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) which creates a url-encoded query string from an array based on key-value pairs.  Then pass the result of that to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `urlencode` is wrong. It's essentially encoding the entire post parameter string when it fact, only the values (not the keys) should be URL encoded.

Additionally, you should consider using the following line instead of yours as the cURL will URL encode everything for you automatically:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  'code' => $code,
  'client_id' => $clientId,
  'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
  'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.org',
  'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
));
```

**Update:** Here's what worked for me:

**Requesting a token**

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_POST => false,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'client_id' => $clientId,
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.org/auth/google/callback',
    'scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
  ),
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
));

$request_result = curl_exec($ch);
```

**Callback**

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_POST => true,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    'code' => $code,
    'client_id' => $clientId,
    'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.org',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
  ),
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
));

$request_result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I am still getting respone as invalid request

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true); By writing this line below CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS now i am getting null

Comment: There. I created an app on Google and tested the code above to make sure it works.